# VMware route host-only VM through dual host-only/NAT VM

Tags: linux, networking, routing, network-interface, vmware

I have a network of test VMs whose traffic I need to go through another VM (in VMware).  I figured the best solution would be to set the 'router' VM to have both a NAT and a host-only adapter and put the test VMs on a host-only network.

I changed **/etc/network/interfaces** on router VM:

```
...
auto vmnet8
iface vmnet8 inet static
  address 10.10.10.15
  gateway 10.10.10.2
  broadcast 10.10.10.255
  netmask 255.255.255.0

auto vmnet9
iface vmnet9 inet static
  address 10.10.11.1
  broadcast 10.10.11.255
  netmask 255.255.255.0
```

And an example VM on the host-only network:

```
...
auto vmnet9
iface vmnet9 inet static 
  address 10.10.11.12
  broadcast 10.10.11.255
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 10.10.11.1
```

I've also set **/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward** to 1 on the router VM

As of right now, the router VM has internet access and can talk to the other VMs but is not forwarding the traffic from the host-only network to the NAT connection.

Answer (score 1):

You need `iptables` rules to forward input on one ethernet dev to output to the other device, and vicey-versa so traffic can flow both ways.  Then you'll need to set appropriate routes on whatever devices you want to connect to your virtual subnet

I use (do the same in virtualbox, one nic on bridged to my LAN, other on "internal only").  I set this as a script to run on boot via rc.local on the "router" VM...

```
#!/bin/bash
/sbin/iptables -F
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thanks! Now my host-only VMs are successfully able to reach the internet but virtualbox is dropping any response packets.  I started wireshark on the host and the router VM and pinged 8.8.8.8 from one of the host-only VMs.  The host and router sees the ICMP request but only the host sees the response (it's not being forwarded by virtualbox).  Have you run into this problem?